# Postman: when the response is image, Postman hides response metadata

Tags: postman

When I make a GET request with Postman to [get a random Unsplash image](https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200), Postman shows me the response image, but hides the response metadata. How can I view response metadata? In particular, I'm interested in the image id, which I'm sure is part of the response, because when I make the same request with my browser, I can see the image id in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the cleanest way to do it, but you could grab the URL as a string and slice it like this;

```
const response = pm.request.url.toString();
    
let photoID = response.match(/unsplash\.com\/(.*?)\?/gm);
    
//remove first and last characters with slice;
console.log(photoID[0].slice(13, -1));
```

[image]